# How to optimize this query without making excessive calls to db using LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this anonymous type that I'm building through repository calls form Entity Framework but am getting this error: `The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.` The code below only pulls from one database so I do not understand why this is being raised.

```
// listOfReportIDs is a list of ints
var reports = BusinessLogic.Repository.Read<Report>().Where(r => listOfReportIDs.Contains(r.ReportID));
var huForm = BusinessLogic.Repository.Read<HumanCase>().Where(h => listOfReportIDs.Contains(h.ReportID));
var anForm = BusinessLogic.Repository.Read<AnimalCase>().Where(a => listOfReportIDs.Contains(a.ReportID));

var reportSummaryData = from r in reports
                        from h in huForm.Where(h => h.ReportID == r.ReportID)
                        from a in anForm.Where(a => a.ReportID == r.ReportID)
                        select new
                        {
                            CDC_ReportID = r.CDCReportID,
                            StateReportID = r.StateReportID,
                            r.ReportDate,
                            ReportStatus = r.LookupReportStatus.LookupReportStatusName,
                            r.AuthorID,
                            h.HumanComment,
                            a.AnimalComment
                        };

var reportData = reportSummaryData.ToList();
```

When I call the ToList() method above at the end (in order to cut down calls to the db til the end), I get the error mentiond above about multiple contexts. They all come from the same single database, just different tables, why is this still being thrown and how can I fix it in order to only make one call to the db?

**EDIT:**

Read method:

```
public IQueryable<T> Read<T>() where T : EntityObject, new()
{
    var objectSet = Context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    objectSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.PreserveChanges;
    return objectSet;
}
```

Comment: Show your `Read()` method

Comment: @haim770 Okay, done.

Comment: So the problem is not that you're trying to call different databased. It's that you're trying to use different `Context` instances together in a single call.

Comment: I suspect that `BusinessLogic.Repository` instanciates a new `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple contexts refers to reports, huForm and anForm.  You need to move these to the same context, or use separate queries to get the data from the database, and join then join the results.

Each of those reads is giving you a separate context.  You need to abstract your db connection and then inherit to each of the models.

Comment: How would I "move them to the same context"? I was trying to limit my db calls to the very end when absolutely necessary. How can I build this query up seeing as it is coming from one db?

Comment: I edited my answer and hopefully clarified what I mean.

Comment: I'm taking this question down, the problem was somewhere else entirely.